# REST how to pass values containing "/" as path parameter in the URI?

Tags: java, rest, get

I am developing a  Client using HttpClient in Java to access a REST Application.
In this i want to pass two parameters name(value="Kiran") and address(Value="5th Corner/Road") as path parameters .

```
Sample url:-http://localhost:port/rest/name/Kiran/address/5th Corner/Road
```

But as address contains "/" as value, its not taking the actual value.
Is there a way to handle "/" while accessing REST applications from Java.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [slashes in url variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Use [java.net.URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode the query parameters.