# How to send a GET request with a "/" in the query

Tags: java, web-services, rest, get

I'm trying to write a test program to test my web service.  I'm sending a JSON object to my web service via the GET method but it's not working.  My test URL looks like this:

```
http://testserver:8080/mydir/{"filename":"test.jpg", "Path":"test/2/2"}
```

I'm thinking the "/" in the path are causing me problems since the program works fine once I remove them.

Per [REST how to pass values containing "/" as path parameter in the URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350768/rest-how-to-pass-values-containing-as-path-parameter-in-the-uri), I've tried to use java.net.URLEncoder.encode but that isn't helping.  Here's a snippet of my test program:

```
// some code from main method
<snip snip>
String url = "http://testserver:8080/mydir/";
String JSON = "{\"filename\":\"test.jpg\",\"Path\":\"test/2/2\"}";
String enc_JSON = URLEncoder.encode(JSON,"UTF-8");
String testGet = url + enc_JSON;
String out2 = TestCode.httpGet(testGet);
<snip snip>

// code from httpGet method
public static String httpGet(String serverURL) {
  URL url;
  HttpURLConnection conn;

  try {
      url = new URL (serverURL);
      conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      conn.setUseCaches(false);
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.connect();
// failing at line below
      InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
<snip snip>
```

The result of my program is I get an HTTP response code: 400.  Did I forget to add something in my code in the httpGet() method that's causing it to fail or am I doing something illegal in my URL due to the JSON object being tacked on at the end with the "/" in the path location?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For REST APIs, JSON objects are typically sent (POST) or returned in the body of the request.  They are not typically encoded as part of the URL.

For a GET request, you can either pass the information as segments in the url or as querystring parameters.

As segments in the url:

```
/resourcetype/{path}/{filename}
http://testserver:8080/resourcetype/test/2/2/test.jpg
```

As querystring params:

```
/resourcetype?path={path}&file={filename}
http://testserver:8080/resourcetype?path=test/2/2&filename=test.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  My POST method was working so I tried to move on to GET and ran into this.  Now on to PUT and DELETE  :)

Thanks again!