# How to get URL having ".../?where={'key1' : 'value1' , 'key2' : 'value2':.........}" in Jmeter http request

Tags: jmeter

I need to load test one Python `api` in below URL format:

```
//IP:PORT/Sub_Part/?where={"KEY1":"VALUE1","KEY2":"VALUE2","KEY3":"VALUE3"}
```

I tried to pass the key value pair through csv as well as directly in http request but getting error message.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 47:
http://IP:PORT/Sub_Part/?where={"KEY1":"VALUE1","KEY2":"VALUE2","KEY3":"VALUE3"}
```

Here key and value are dummy data I have placed here for easy understanding.

Please help me with correct syntax for this URL.
Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In REST APIs, JSON objects are typically sent (POST) or returned in the body of the request. They are not typically encoded as part of the URL.

For a GET request, you can either pass the information as segments in the url or as querystring parameters.

For more details refer here, [How to send a GET request with a "/" in the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944458/how-to-send-a-get-request-with-a-in-the-query)

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp):

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the [ASCII character-set](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp).

so you need to define the request in JMeter's [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) as follows:

[image]

Pay attention to `URL Encode?` checkbox, it has to be ticked otherwise the parameter will be sent "as is"

Another option is using [__urlencode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function like:

```
http://IP:PORT/Sub_Part/?where=${__urlencode({"KEY1":"VALUE1"\,"KEY2":"VALUE2"\,"KEY3":"VALUE3"})}
```

which will generate an encoded sequence which you could use in the URL path:

```
%7B%22KEY1%22%3A%22VALUE1%22%2C%22KEY2%22%3A%22VALUE2%22%2C%22KEY3%22%3A%22VALUE3%22%7D
```

as you can see, all non-ASCII characters where removed.

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.