# Using GET method to retrieve data from API using a name

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson, jetty

i'm building a REST API and was wondering how i would go about retrieving a user data by using his name. I currently have the URI example.com/rest/users/{name} , however if someone contain a slash in his name this wouldn't work. So How would i do this? (using Jersey)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
 example.com/rest/users?name={encoded name}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you check this one?

[slashes in url variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables)

It mentions that

```
You need to escape the slashes as %2F
```