# Flask passing another url through url variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-development-server

I'm trying to build a cors proxy through flask from scratch. Here's my code

```
@app.route('/api/v1/cors/url=<name>&method=<method>', methods=['GET'])
def api_cors(name, method):
    if method == 'http' or method == 'https':
        r = request.urlopen(method+"://"+name)
        return r.read()
    else:
        return "method not set!"
```

It is working good so far but I have one problem, when I pass "url=google.com&method=https" it is working fine but when I pass something like "url=google.com/images/image.jpg&method=https" the "/" will considered as a new directory

Is there anyway to evade this in flask?

Comment: can you try with keeping it between inverted commas like  "url='google.com/images/image.jpg'&method=https"

Comment: @SunilT how would i go about doing that, wouldnt it be bypassed anyway

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables.. seems there are multiple solutions to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use the same URL scheme that you're using now, change your routing decorator to this and it will work.

```
@app.route('/api/v1/cors/url=<path:name>&method=<method>', methods=['GET'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't try and pass the value as part of the route itself. Pass it as a query parameter.

```
@app.route('/api/v1/cors/')
def api_cors():
    url = request.args.get('url')
```

and call it as `"/api/v1/cors/?url=https://google.com/images/image.jpg"`.

Comment: hey i get attribute error when doing the same as you did

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'args'

Comment: i did import request btw,:
from flask import request

Comment: Do you have a `request.py` that you import somewhere?

Comment: have it where? isnt it supposed to come as a package, plus i dont get any import errors

Comment: I want to get the url without using `?url=` any possibility?

Comment: For people having issues with `request`, try `from flask import request`.