# How to escape SLASH in URL in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url

I am trying to escape SLASH in URL. Lets say, I would like to pass "1/2 inch steel pipe" as a URL parameter. Here is the URL below...

```
http://localhost/Product/1/2 inch steel pipe
```

Product/ is an action and "1/2 inch steel pipe" is the parameter. Because of the SLASH between 1 and 2, It looks for a Action named as "1". Therefore, it throws "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found"

Is there an excape character for SLASH? any suggestions?

Comment: %2f represents a slash: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236038/1661209 I think you should encode your url, or think of a url-safe querystring parameter.

Comment: Why not use /half-inch-steel-pipe?

Comment: He probably has no control over the product titles (Or they're externally provided)

Comment: encodeURIComponent("1/2 inch steel pipe") use encodeuricomponent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables?answertab=oldest#tab-top Please check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add asterisks to your parameter in route annotation like this

```
[Route("/RouteName/{*parameterName}")]
```

The asterisk (*) allows the parameter to include slashes