# How can I manage the url if a variable contains a slash?

Tags: javascript, url

I have built an API using Django REST framework and I want to make a PUT request from my AngularJS web-app.

The problem occurs when the id consists of characters like "/".

An example could be the following:

- id = "text/additionalText"
- url: https://domainName.com/api/record/**text/additionalText**

So, as you can expect, the above parsed as 2 parameters and I get 404 (NOT FOUND).

I read this post ([slashes in url variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables)) and then I tried to encode the id to "text%2FadditionalText" (using encodeURIComponent function) but didn't decoded from my server.

I can not change the id because it constructed by some other fields (user input), in order to be human readable.

Comment: Is the addtionalText always in the request? If it's the case you can try to code your urlpattern as: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^record/(.*?)/(.*?)/$', views.your_view),]

Comment: It depends on some other fields which are coming from the user input. So sometimes the id could be  "texttext" and some others could be "text/text".

Comment: encodeURIComponent is the right solution in the client, you need to look at your server...depending on the webserver, some automatically translate the url_encoding back (which would be bad in your case), some do give the encoded to the script handler, so you will need to call a url_decode function in your serverside script

Comment: Seems that you're right. I saw in logs of my server that the url is exactly the same with which I'm sending from client. I thought that this process (decode the url) invoked automatically from Django REST framework.