# How to handle name with slash as one path param in url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a route in app.js like

```
.when('/provider/:id/app/:aName', {                            
        templateUrl: 'templates/provider/form.html',
        controller: 'YourController'
    });
```

in html:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-href="#/provider/{{id}}/app/{{appName}}">Edit</a>
```

However my appName will contain slashes, such as abc/test
so with **inputs id = 1 and appName = abc/test, href will become**

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-href="#/provider/1/app/abc/test">Edit</a>
```

This is causing a problem, because my code presumes that the slash in the application name represents a different section of the website, the above href fails. So the URL will fail.

How to manage the app name with slash in url that is abc/test. Any help on this will be really helpful.

I have looked into this post [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables), but unable to implement the same in my code. If I replace **/** with **%2F** then the app name changes. How to encode URL without affecting the actual app name

Comment: try `'/provider/:id/app/:aName*'`

Comment: <a class="btn btn-warning" ng--href="#/provider/{{id}}/app/{{ 
 encodeURIComponent(appName)}}">Edit</a>

Comment: @AlekseySolovey if I try /provider/:id/app/:aName* then only abc will come as appName whereas I should get appName as abc/test