# POSTMAN cannot handle backslash within endpoint

Tags: postman

I'm having problem while running a request in POSTMAN

This is my ENDPOINT:

> {{URL_API}}/products/96PHLFR71B/03

I want to obtain the information related to a product but the SKU itself has a **backslash** so the program fails because it cannot understand the code. Take a look:

[image]

The product DOES exist but i was not able to make it work. Can you help me?

Comment: Escape the slash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables

Comment: Yeah,  i was using something different :/. %2F seems to be the way to go!. Thanks buddy :D