# php session getting reset on using image\

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a simple login script

After veryfying user I am creating a session

```
$home_url ="domainname";
$_SESSION["user_session"] = "welcome";    
header("Location: ".$home_url."template.php"); exit();
```

template.php

```
echo "Session is " . $_SESSION["user_session"] . ".<br>";
```

It works perfectly file until I add the following line in my code in template.php

```
$banner1 = $home_url.'images/banner-2.jpg';
```

If I just remove / after images code works

```
$banner1 = $home_url.'imagesbanner-2.jpg';
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Got some hint from the link [slashes in url variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables)

I am getting issue with / in img path (Guess particularly background image)

Replacing

```
data-bg-image="/img/category/<?php echo $sub_category;?>_banner.jpg"
```

with

```
data-bg-image="%2Fimg%2Fcategory%2F<?php echo $sub_category;?>_banner.jpg"
```

Resolved the issue.

But not sure why this is happening only with img