# Consecutive double slashes in URL query string is resolved to 1 slash, NodeJs Express

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Please I am working on a project that takes the req.query part of a url and checks if its a correct fraction or not i.e.

1/2          // This is a valid fraction
1//2       // This is an Invalid fraction

The problem is when it receives a URL like this https://rough-volcano-starburst.glitch.me/api/convert?input=1//2gal

```
app.route('/api/convert')
    .get(function (req, res){
      let input =  req.query.input;

}
```

The input variable shows '1/2gal'

It doesn't matter how many slashes I put, I still get 1/2gal.

Please help.

Comment: Hello Welcome to SE!  Use post or escape https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [slashes in url variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables)

Comment: Hi @CharybdeBE thanks for the response. I already tried encoding it but it only returns 1%2F2gal instead of 1%2F%2F2gal

Comment: You encode when you send and then you decode when you receive, and then you can evaluate if its a correct fraction

Comment: Hi @CharybdeBE, let me explain further. I wrote a freecodecamp project. When i submit my solution link, it runs my code against FCC test cases which means there is no way for me to encode their URL variable before it reaches my function                                                                                               ```app.route('/api/convert').get(function (req, res){
      let input =  req.query.input;                                                                                           }                                                                                  ```