# dbt Cloud airflow conn_id from secret manager breaking parsing

Tags: airflow, aws-secrets-manager, airflow-2.x, dbt-cloud

I'm using aws secret manager to store my connections in airflow.
So when creating the dbt connection string in the secret , i followed this pattern
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-dbt-cloud/1.0.2/connections.html

dbt-cloud://account_id:api_token@

eg: dbt-cloud://111:dbts_-abc/Qo==@

The api_token generated by dbtcloud has a "/ "in it and is causing an error.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/parse.py", line 172, in port
port = int(port, 10)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dbts_-abc'
```

Did anybody run into this issue before? How do i fix this?
If I just use the airflow connections ui to get the api_token then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape forward slashes with `%2F` when you generate the URI. Check out [this related StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables).

Also, the Airflow docs show an easy way to [generate the Connection URI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#generating-a-connection-uri) too.